# Understanding softmax classifier

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, gradient-descent, calculus, softmax

I am trying to understand a simple implementation of Softmax classifier from this link - [CS231n - Convolutional Neural Networks for Visual Recognition](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-case-study/). Here they implemented a simple softmax classifier. In the example of Softmax Classifier on the link, there are random 300 points on a 2D space and a label associated with them. The softmax classifier will learn which point belong to which class.

Here is the full code of the softmax classifier. Or you can see the link I have provided.

```
# initialize parameters randomly
W = 0.01 * np.random.randn(D,K)
b = np.zeros((1,K))

# some hyperparameters
step_size = 1e-0
reg = 1e-3 # regularization strength

# gradient descent loop
num_examples = X.shape[0]
for i in xrange(200):

   # evaluate class scores, [N x K]
   scores = np.dot(X, W) + b 

   # compute the class probabilities
   exp_scores = np.exp(scores)
   probs = exp_scores / np.sum(exp_scores, axis=1, keepdims=True) # [N x K]

   # compute the loss: average cross-entropy loss and regularization
   corect_logprobs = -np.log(probs[range(num_examples),y])
   data_loss = np.sum(corect_logprobs)/num_examples
   reg_loss = 0.5*reg*np.sum(W*W)
   loss = data_loss + reg_loss
   if i % 10 == 0:
   print "iteration %d: loss %f" % (i, loss)

   # compute the gradient on scores
   dscores = probs
   dscores[range(num_examples),y] -= 1
   dscores /= num_examples

   # backpropate the gradient to the parameters (W,b)
   dW = np.dot(X.T, dscores)
   db = np.sum(dscores, axis=0, keepdims=True)

   dW += reg*W # regularization gradient

   # perform a parameter update
   W += -step_size * dW
   b += -step_size * db
```

I cant understand how they computed the gradient here. I assume that they computed the gradient here -

```
   dW = np.dot(X.T, dscores)
   db = np.sum(dscores, axis=0, keepdims=True)
   dW += reg*W # regularization gradient
```

But How? I mean Why gradient of `dW` is `np.dot(X.T, dscores)`? And Why the gradient of `db` is `np.sum(dscores, axis=0, keepdims=True)`?? So how they computed the gradient on weight and bias? Also why they computed the `regularization gradient`?

I am just starting to learn about convolutional neural networks and deep learning. And I heard that `CS231n - Convolutional Neural Networks for Visual Recognition` is a good starting place for that. I did not know where to place deep learning related post. So, i placed them on stackoverflow. If there is any place to post questions related to deep learning please let me know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The gradients start being computed here:

```
# compute the gradient on scores
dscores = probs
dscores[range(num_examples),y] -= 1
dscores /= num_examples
```

First, this sets `dscores` equal to the probabilities computed by the softmax function. Then, it subtracts `1` from the probabilities computed for the correct classes in the second line, and then it divides by the number of training samples in the third line.

Why does it subtract `1`? Because you want the probabilities of the correct labels to be `1`, ideally. So it subtracts what it should predict from what it actually predicts: if it predicts something close to `1`, the subtraction will be a large negative number (close to zero), so the gradient will be small, because you're close to a solution. Otherwise, it will be a small negative number (far from zero), so the gradient will be bigger, and you'll take larger steps towards the solution.

Your activation function is simply `w*x + b`. Its derivative with respect to `w` is `x`, which is why `dW` is the dot product between `x` and the gradient of the scores / output layer.

The derivative of `w*x + b` with respect to `b` is `1`, which is why you simply sum `dscores` when backpropagating.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping out. Just one thing I'm not getting. My activation function is `w*x+b`. So if i compute `dW`, (i mean the gradient on `W`) it is `x`(as you have mentioned). So why do I need to use a dot product between `x` and the gradient of the scores?(I mean why `dW = np.dot(X.T, dscores)`)? What it actually does?

Comment: @S_kar that is the final gradient of `W`. You can take the derivative of the entire thing, starting from the output layer, and using the chain rule you'll get that. It will get ugly, so I only gave the intuition for what `X` appears: because the derivative of the activation function is `X`. The chain rule will make it clearer if you wish to compute everything. Backpropagation is basically just the continuous application of the  chain rule: derivative of `g(f(x))` is `g'(f(x)) * f'(x) * x'`.

Comment: So using the chain rule i will get `dW = X*dscore`? Now, if the chain rule is `g(f(x)) is g'(f(x)) * f'(x) * x'` , then if activation function is `f = w*x + b` then by chain rule, I'm getting `dW = x`. Then why don't i subtract it from `w` directly? (`W += -step_size * dW`)? I'm new in this topic, so you know i'm having a hard time understanding this. Sorry if i'm missing some obvious points.

Comment: @S_kar your output layer activation function is the softmax. You need to start computing derivatives from where you apply softmax, and then make use of the chain rule. You don't start from `f = w*x + b`. This `f` further gets fed into the softmax function, so that's where you start from.

Comment: Can you provide some links for getting some intuition on this?

Comment: @S_kar http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Softmax_Regression and http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf - the second one focuses on simple logistic regression (without softmax), but the ideas remain the same.

Comment: thanks for this. Also is it possible to contact you directly? via mail or other option? I'm just starting on this topic and there is not many people in my area who can help me out of this.

Comment: @S_kar I have an e-mail in my profile. I answer as time allows.

Comment: @IVlad your answer provides an intuitive understanding of the subtraction of 1. But can you explain what is the reason behind the division by the num_examples in the next step?

Answer (score 0):

### Gradient Descent

Backpropagation is to reduce the cost `J` of the entire system (softmax classifier here) and it is a problem to optimize the weight parameter `W` to minimize the cost. Providing the cost function `J = f(W)` is **convex**, the gradient descent `W = W - α * f'(W)` will result in the `Wmin` which minimizes `J`. The hyperparameter  `α` is called **learning rate** which we need to optimize too, but not in this answer.

`Y` should be read as `J` in the diagram. Imagine you are on the surface of a place whose shape is defined as `J = f(W)` and you need to reach the point `Wmin`. There is no gravity so you do not know which way is toward the bottom but you know the function and your coordinate. How do you know which way you should go? You can find the direction from the derivative `f'(W)` and move to a new coordinate by `W = W - α * f'(W)`. By repeating this, you can get closer and closer to the point `Wmin`.

[image]

### Back propagation at Affin Layer

At the node where multiply or dot operation happens (affin), the function is `J = f(W) = X * W`. Suppose there are `m` number of fixed two dimensional coordinates represented as X. How can we find the hyper-plane which minimizes `J = f(W) = X * W` and its vector `W`?

We can get closer to the optimal `W` by repeating the gradient descent `W += -α * X` if **α** is appropriate.

[image]

### Chain Rule

When there are layers after the Affine layer such as the **softmax** layer and the **log loss** layer in the softmax classifier, we can calculate the gradient with the chain rule. In the diagram, replace **sigmoid** with **softmax**.

[image]

As stated in [Computing the Analytic Gradient with Backpropagation](https://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-case-study/#grad) in the cs321 page, the gradient contribution from the **softmax** layer and the **log loss** layer is the **dscore** part. See the Note section below too.

[image]

By applying the gradient to that of the **affine** layer via the chain rule, the code is derived where **α** is replaced with **step_size**. In reality, the **step_size** needs to be learned as well.

```
dW = np.dot(X.T, dscores)
W += -step_size * dW
```

The bias gradient can be derived by applying the chain rule towards the bias **b** with the gradients (**dscore**) from the post layers.

```
db = np.sum(dscores, axis=0, keepdims=True)
```

### Regularization

As stated in [Regularization](https://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/#reg) of the cs231 page, the cost function (objective) is adjusted by adding the regularization, which is **reg_loss** in the code. It is to reduce the over-fitting. The intuition is, in my understanding, if specific feature(s) cause overfitting, we can reduce it by inflating the cost with their weight parameters **W**, because the gradient descent will work to reduce the cost contributions from the weights. Since we do not know which ones, use all **W**.  The reason of **0.5 * W*W** is because it gives simple derivative **W**.

```
reg_loss = 0.5*reg*np.sum(W*W)
```

The gradient contribution `reg*W` is from the derivative of **reg_loss**. The **reg** is a hyper parameter to be learned in the real training.

```
reg_loss/dw -> 0.5 * reg * 2 * W
```

It is added to the gradient from the layers after the affin.

```
dW += reg*W # regularization gradient
```

The process to get the derivative from the cost including the regularization is omitted in the cs231 page referenced in the post, probably because it is a common practice to just put the gradient of the regularization, but confusing for those who are learning. See Coursera [Machine Learning Week 3 Cost Function](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/B1MnL/cost-function) by Andrew Ng for the regularization.

### Note

[image]

The bias parameter **b** is substituted with **X0** as the bias can be omitted by shifting to the base.

[image]